# Can't mount an IDE HDD - "can't read superblock" error message

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I'm trying to mount my HDD,  `/dev/sdb`, which is connected via an enclosure but every time I try do so I get an error message

```
mount: /dev/sdb: can't read superblock
```

How do I solve this problem and mount my HDD?

Answer (score 39):

Test this:

Connect your Hdd.

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
fdisk -l
```

Suppose that fdisk reports that the partition hdd is /dev/sdb1, continue running:

```
fsck -y /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: Hello, it didn't detect the HDD.
it detected /dev/sda1 on which ubuntu is running instead.

Comment: The drive is likely a goner. Start searching for answers regarding data recovery if you have needed data on the drive.

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: This worded for me. We Can't have acces to a partition: /dev/sda, but this solved the problem, put in the terminal: fsck -y /dev/sda5

Answer (score 4):

I realise this is an old thread but I will add this just in case it helps someone. I have also had similar problems with and external disk in the past which I think were linked to usb power problems. I got the person I was helping to try the disk in a powered usb hub and this made it visible and mountable. Try that before throwing the disk away as it may be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and solved it with testdisk. Using this info: [Advanced FAT Repair | CGSecurity](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Advanced_FAT_Repair)