# Error: Can't Read Superblock On Dev/SB1

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

Just got a System76 laptop last week running Ubuntu 18.04 with a 2TB SSD as an extra drive I am using as "cold storage" for files. This morning when I went to add something to it, the drive would not mount. The error I am receiving is...

Can't read superblock on dev/sb1

How do I fix this? Searching online is giving me results from many years ago and I want to make sure I using the most up to date solution. Thanks!

Comment: Probably sdb1? What format is sdb1 partition? Post this: `sudo parted -l` Then first thing to try is fsck if ext4 or from Windows chkdsk if NTFS. http://askubuntu.com/questions/642504/ubuntu-14-04-is-not-booting-normaly-after-a-manual-hard-boot/642789#642789 And if NTFS did you write with Windows 10. Then it may be hibernated. http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Yep! FSCK fixed it. I found the solution here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/539880/cant-mount-an-ide-hdd-cant-read-superblock-error-message?rq=1

Comment: Errors like that are often caused by system not fully unmounted when disconnected. Make sure all writing is done and unmount before unplugging any external device.