# Unable to access an external hard drive. Error mounting. Can't read superblock

Tags: mount, hard-drive, data-recovery, hardware, external-hdd

I have an external hard drive with an EXT4 file system, which I use to back up my laptop and save several important files. This hard drive had some sort of security layer (probably prepared with GParted by my colleague), so that I had to use "sudo" to write on it, and so that files could not be read with usual desktop software.

Unfortunately, I had a problem on this disk. I couldn't remove the disk safely as usual. And so I had to manually disconnect it from the laptop. Then, when I tried to read this disk again, I had the error mentioned here: [Can't mount an IDE HDD - "can't read superblock" error message](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539880/cant-mount-an-ide-hdd-cant-read-superblock-error-message) . Everything became extremely slow to read on this disk, and I could not practically use it.

As far as I could understand the error online, I had to run the following command:

```
fsck -y /dev/sdb1
```

So I ran it for about 12 hours. It processed a lot of stuff, but then I had to leave and so I had to interrupt the command which couldn't complete.

I now have the following error when I connect this disk to my laptop:

```
Unable to access Disk_name. Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/username/Disk_name : can't read superblock on /dev/sdb1
```

(where Disk_name is the name of my hdd). And I don't see the disk on the command line anymore. I only see it through the default desktop user interface. Do you know how I can fix or bypass this problem?

I've seen some contradictory answers on various posts. Some say you have to run fsck ([Can't mount an IDE HDD - "can't read superblock" error message](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539880/cant-mount-an-ide-hdd-cant-read-superblock-error-message)) and some say you shouldn't do it (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/680299/mount-cant-read-superblock-on-dev-sda5). So I'm confused...

I also tried applying this solution (https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/fix-cant-read-superblock-error) but it leaves me with errors:

```
root@laptop:~# sudo e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sdb1 
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Superblock needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data.
Recovery flag not set in backup superblock, so running journal anyway.
Disk_name: recovering journal
Error reading block 243826716 (Input/output error).  Ignore error<y>? 
no
Disk_name: Input/output error while reading block 243826716

JBD2: Failed to read block at offset 28
e2fsck: Input/output error while recovering journal of Disk_name
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Error reading block 235930218 (Input/output error) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? no
Error while scanning inodes (58991744): Can't read next inode

Disk_name: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
e2fsck: aborted

Disk_name: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
```

What should I try next ? Should I say yes when I'm asked to ignore errors with e2fsck ? Thanks a lot for any advice.

Comment: I/O errors in this context almost always indicate hardware failure so it's probably a waste of time and electricity trying to error correct it by software which is applicable only to logical errors.

Comment: Have you checked the health of your drive?  Given IO errors I'd **not** be attempting to perform any `fsck` or file-system checks as you risk doing damage on a failing drive & maybe causing data loss.  Check the drive health first (*which doesn't involve any change, not even a read/write of the drive surface unless you choose to as it's from drive stats on chips*) - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools  *You didn't provide any OS/release details, and some external drives don't have SMART but they are few*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice. I think I should try to rsync the whole hdd to a new hard drive, then perform repairs, right ? I tested "sudo smartctl -i  /dev/sdb1" and I got: "SMART support is:     Unavailable - device lacks SMART capability." Does that mean I cannot apply the tests from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools ?