# Recovering data from HDD

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I used to have a problem with WD Mycloud Gen 2, but I replaced an HDD with a new one and now it's working. But I need to read my old data from an old HDD (WD RED 3 TB)
In Disk Utility I see the structure, as it is supposed to be:
[image: here's the screenshot]
My data is on sda2 - which supposed to be ext4
In the terminal, I see that partition table entries are not in order:
[image: screenshot]
When I turn it on it mounts some of the disks (sometimes 2 GB, sometimes 577 MB)

**how do I mount the sda2 to read and recover my data?**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 2.73 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Disk model: YZWY_TECH       
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 37DD4E4B-5AC5-4D4D-941D-1EBC66D2A928

Device        Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1      2048    4196351    4194304    2G Linux swap
/dev/sda2  16779264 5860533134 5843753871  2.7T Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3  14682112   16779263    2097152    1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4   4196352    6293503    2097152    1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5   6293504    8390655    2097152    1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6   8390656   12584959    4194304    2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda7  12584960   14682111    2097152    1G Microsoft basic data

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/md0: 2 GiB, 2144337920 bytes, 4188160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 6EAF41D9-D069-4386-94BA-CCC5F52E2D66

Device       Start     End Sectors  Size Type
/dev/md0p1    2048 1128447 1126400  550M Linux filesystem
/dev/md0p2 1128448 4188126 3059679  1.5G Linux filesystem
root@UNIXBOOX:/home/sam# mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
mount: /mnt: can't read superblock on /dev/sda2.
```

The disk used to work normally as NAS, but during December failed a couple of times and then got stuck in indexing...
I didn't do anything with the original partitions.

Thank you

Comment: I’d be worried your hardware is failing; have a look here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1422934/unable-to-access-an-external-hard-drive-error-mounting-cant-read-superblock - and search online for the error message you’re getting, there are quite a few posts on this subject. Most people seem to advise cloning your failing drive to another drive (eg using dd) and work on the clone to avoid corrupting your data further.